# How to determine reponse time of fsockopen()

Tags: php, sockets, fsockopen

I am developing a project in which i am creating a socket using `fsockopen()` in a php script to connect to a java server on the same machine only.
Is there anyway to know time  it takes for a response to be returned for a request made to the java server ?
sorry for the bad english..an yhelp or guidance appreciated

Comment: Suppose you could time it with microtime, there is an example of a timing script on the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Comment: ok will give it a try

Comment: you can set max_execution_time to make sure it waits for only specific amount of time..

Comment: i have a `timeout()` function that checks it ,i want to check the response time!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to do this as a one-off you could either use `xdebug` to profile a request or `strace` on the process with timing enabled. A more crude method to time this would be to compare `microtime()` values before/after the call.